# Ubuntu default port permissions

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am trying to communicate with an external GPS device using UART on a Raspberry Pi, but I am having some issues with the default permissions on the serial port.

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -la /dev/ttyS0
    crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 64 Jul  2 17:43 /dev/ttyS0
```

As you can see, the group 'tty' only has permission to write to the port, not read. This then leads to 'permission denied' messages when I try to read from the port in Python. I have been working around the problem for now using:

```
    sudo chmod g+r /dev/ttyS0
```

But this wont work forever, as the goal is for this port to be used automatically after startup.

Is there a way to change the default permissions so that the group 'tty' always has read access?

Running the unofficial Ubuntu 16.04 release on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Have you looked at /etc/udev/rules.d/? Maybe you can make your change permanent there.

Comment: @TeTeT I have started looking into that, but i haven't managed to solve the issue. I have created a new file in that folder, 10-serial.rules, and added this line: KERNEL=="ttyS0",SUBSYSTEM=="tty",DRIVER=="",OWNER="tty",MODE="0660"
Nothing has changed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Those are not the conventional Linux defaults.  The group is typically "dialout", and the  group permissions "-rw".  Look for the assignments in the **/lib/udev/rules.d/** directory, perhaps the file **40-inputattach.rules**.